# cmd command through powershell fails with error "The string is missing the terminator: '."

Tags: powershell, cmd

I originally had a .bat script with the following code:

```
cmd /V:ON /C "set unique=nets /ao&&FOR %%A IN (0 1 2 3 2 6 2 4 5 6 0 7 1337) DO set final=!final!!unique:~%%A,1!&& IF %%A==1337 CALL !final:~-12!"
```

this just executes "netstat /ao". It just reconstructs each element based on an index in the loop.

To experiment further, I tried to run the following command in cmd but through powershell. The command I used was the following:

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList '/c cmd /V:ON /K \"set unique=nets /ao&&FOR %A IN (0 1 2 3 2 6 2 4 5 6 0 7 1337) DO set final=!final!!unique:~%A,1!&& IF %A==1337 CALL !final:~-12!\"'"
```

but I get the following error:

```
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

I tried playing with the arguments and the way I execute the command but I always land on the same error. Any idea what Im doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you run one CLI to run another CLI to run some CLI commands?

Comment: @Olaf Im just experimenting.

Comment: You have an issue with your quotes. Instead of escaping them with a backslash double or triple them. ☝

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your stated goal, i.e. run the command in cmd:

```bash
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Start-Process -FilePath \"$Env:SystemRoot\System32\cmd.exe\" -ArgumentList \"/V:On /D /K `\"@Set `\"unique=nets /ao`\" & For %G In (0 1 2 3 2 6 2 4 5 6 0 7 1337) Do @Set `\"final=!final!!unique:~%G,1!`\" & If %G Equ 1337 !final:~-12!`\"\""
```

For clarification:

The code is first parsed in cmd.exe, which requires that the nested `-Command` doublequotes are escaped. This is done using a backward slash.

This means powershell.exe sees this `-Command`:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "$Env:SystemRoot\System32\cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/V:On /D /K `"@Set `"unique=nets /ao`" & For %G In (0 1 2 3 2 6 2 4 5 6 0 7 1337) Do @Set `"final=!final!!unique:~%G,1!`" & If %G Equ 1337 !final:~-12!`""
```

The remaining code for PowerShell requires that the nested doublequotes within the correctly doublequoted `/K` argument string are escaped. This is done using backticks, as seen above.

This means the resulting `/K` argument string for the `-FilePath` executable is:

```bash
"@Set "unique=nets /ao" & For %G In (0 1 2 3 2 6 2 4 5 6 0 7 1337) Do @Set "final=!final!!unique:~%G,1!" & If %G Equ 1337 !final:~-12!"
```

The actual `/K` string for `cmd.exe` in this case does not require that nested doublequtes are escaped. If you weren't sure, after reading the Command Prompt output from `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /?`, you could have considered using the `/S` option, (along with my best practice use of the `/D` option).

You should note that I replaced your unnecessary `&&` instances with `&` and removed your incorrect use of the `Call` command too. I also doublequoted your `set` commands, as is recommended practice.